# Not able to insert select list value for CCK field, while creating node programmatically from a from

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cck, drupal-forms

I am creating node after submission of some selected values of my custom made form. There is a CCK field in my content type called "Start Time(field_starttime)" for which I am selecting value from a select box in my form and trying to submit. But it's not getting done.
Code in form for select list -

```
$select = taskform_timeelements();
  $form['fromtime'] = array(
    '#type' => 'select', 
    '#title' => t('From'),     
    '#options' => $select,
    '#prefix' => '<table><tr><td>',
    '#suffix' => '</td>',

  );
```

Where function for select list values looks like -

```
function taskform_timeelements(){   
    $hour = range(9,19);
    $select = array();
    foreach($hour as $record){  
        $select[$record.":00"] = $record.":00";
    }
    return $select;
}
```

Line which I have used for assigning value to the destined CCK field -

```
$node->field_starttime[]['value'] = $form_state['values']['fromtime';
```

Even I tried with this line -

```
 $node->field_starttime[]['value'] = '09:00';
```

But nothing happened. Node just got saved without any value for this CCK field.

Comment: Tried by setting the delta value directly ?
$node->field_starttime[0]['value'] = '09:00';

and do other fields get saved correctly ?

Comment: Yes other fields are getting saved..like user reference field, body. There is no other CCK apart from this user reference & I am able to map global user in that..
And "YES" I tried setting the value directly but it didn't take..
I really can't understand why it's happening..